# Unable to Create web app bot from Azure portal using free subscription

Tags: azure, azureportal

Unable to Create web app bot from Azure portal.

Getting error like this "We're having problems communicating with the server. Click to contact Azure Support."

I have tried near 5 different location but the result is same.
Can anyone help me in this.

Comment: Unfortunately, as written, this is too broad and unclear what's happening. Seems like it's unrelated to a programming issue, but without more details it's impossible to know. Please edit with specifics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was mitigated. Could you please re-try and let us know?

Kindly review the Service health page on the Azure Portal to find more details on this issue.

The ‘Service Health’ -Service issues view shows any ongoing problems in Azure services that are impacting your resources. You can understand when the issue began, and what services and regions are impacted. You can also read the most recent update to understand what Azure is doing to resolve the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.Now i am able to create the Web App bot.

Comment: AjayKumar / @Srinivas - I'm not sure what was "mitigated" - this really doesn't seem like a programming question, rather some type of transient outage? I'd suggest deleting this question (and answer).